# How to get parent DOM container with reference from a component loaded by router-outlet in Angular 12?

Tags: javascript, angular, router, angular12, router-outlet

I have a main layout for the app:

```
<div #layoutContainer class="layout__container">
    <div class="layout__container__sidebar">
        <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
    </div>
    <div class="layout__container__content">
        <div class="layout__container__content-header">
            <div class="header-brand">
                <span *ngIf="isSideNavBarCollapsed">{{ headerBarTitle }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div #layoutContainerContentBody class="layout__container__content-body">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you noticed I have two references #layoutContainer and #layoutContainerContentBody. I need that any component loaded from router-outlet has access to both referenced divs.

The references I put were just trying this to work but not success.

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask for the reason, that the routed components need to access something above them in the DOM? One way to go would be, creating an injectable service, which holds those references and provides them to other components. but I'm not sure if this is helps you out